# Can't connect to SQL Server - Internal connection fatal error

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm just starting out with C# and Windows Forms, so please don't yell at me if you see a big security hole (I would like to know). Every time I run this it gives me a `Internal connection fatal error` with the following stack trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryProcessHeader()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByteArray(Byte[] buff, Int32 offset, Int32 len, Int32& totalRead)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Program.Login.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in i:\Users\Me\Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Program\Program\Login.cs:line 57
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Here is the code for it:

```
            //Begin SQL connection
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=tcp:**.**.**.**,3306;Initial Catalog=******;User ID=*****;Password=*****"))
            {
                conn.Open();

                string UserName = txtUsername.Text;

                string Password = txtPassword.Text;

                //Hash password
                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoder = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes(Password);
                SHA1CryptoServiceProvider cryptoTransformSHA1 =
                new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
                string hash = BitConverter.ToString(
                    cryptoTransformSHA1.ComputeHash(buffer)).Replace("-", "");

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = @username AND password = @password", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", UserName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", hash);

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr = null;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                conn.Close();

                if (dr.Read())
                {

                    if (UserName == dr["username"].ToString() && hash == dr["password"].ToString())
                    {
                        Form1 f = new Form1();
                        f.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errorProvider1.SetError(txtUsername, "Your username and/or password are incorrect.");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: @DavidG The debugger gives me an `InvalidOperationException was unhandled` error on the `conn.Open();` line. I had some trouble configuring the SQL earlier and I thought I got it working by using tcp and adding the port.

Comment: Check out [http://connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com) to learn what a valid SQL Server connection string looks like. Yours smells like MySQL - not SQL Server

Comment: @marc_s Yes, it is MySQL. I come from PHP, where SQL is a breeze.

Comment: SQL Server is a breeze, too - if you do it correctly :-)

Comment: @marc_s I meant it is a breeze to me since I know it already :P

When I try using this format: `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;`

it says it can't connect to the server. I know all of the information is correct.

Comment: The information might be correct - the connection string format isn't quite up to snuff for SQL Server. You typically use something like `server=(servername);database=(databaseName);Integrated security=SSPI;` if you want to use "integrated security" (using your Windows credentials to log in), or `server=(servername);database=(databaseName);user id=(username);password=(your password)` if you want to explicitly specify a username/password combo

Comment: Use `user id=(username)` instead of `uid=(username)`, and spell out `password=(yourpassword)` instead of `pwd=(yourpassword)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58121/discussion-between-chrisrockgm-and-marc-s).

Comment: I was using SQL instead of MySQL

Comment: I’m voting to close. If you’re trying to use mssql client to connect to MySQL, then that’s clearly wrong. Otherwise, the question needs to be edited for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MySql, then you need to use `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`

`MySqlConnection` is for MySql databases. `SqlConnection` is for MSSql databases. Don't mix the two.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 1433 port which is for MSSQL, not 3306 which by my knowledge is for MySQL.

Comment: I use MySQL, not MSSQL.